# Can ping 8.8.4.4 but not 8.8.8.8

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, ping

I'm on a windows 8.1 laptop, and when I ping 8.8.8.8 the request times out, but 8.8.4.4 works fine. I tried restarting, resetting the network adapter, reconnecting, but it still doesn't work.

tracert 8.8.8.8 gives this result, it keeps slowly getting longer:

```
Tracing route to google-public-dns-a.google.com [8.8.8.8]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

Another windows 7 laptop on the same wifi can ping 8.8.8.8 with no problems.

When I switch my 8.1 laptop to my phone's tethering wifi, it can ping 8.8.8.8 fine, but connecting back to the regular wifi it stops working again.

I looked through the router settings and don't see anything that looks like it would block a single IP for a single user.

Comment: What happens if you reboot (restart) your router?

Comment: My first question too, same as DavidPostill, have you rebooted the router?

Comment: Ok, I just restarted the router and now it works. Weird because a few hours ago I also restarted it.

Answer (score 2):

The Google DNS servers ( IPv4: 8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4 - IPv6: 2001:4860:4860::8888 & 2001:4860:4860::8844 ) are examples of DNS servers which employ Anycast, a network addressing and routing methodology in which datagrams from a single sender are routed to the topologically nearest node in a group of potential receivers, though it may be sent to several nodes, all identified by the same destination address.

Therefor the server you get routed to is not necessarily the same server I would get routed to, given our likely geographical remoteness. Having said this, I can independently verify that I am able to communicate with Google's IPv4 and IPv6 DNS servers at this time. What I would do if you merely wish to restore functional DNS resolution, is set 8.8.4.4 as your Primary DNS and set 4.2.2.2 as your Secondary DNS - This is actually the configuration I choose to utilize, 8.8.4.4 is the least used of the two Google DNS servers and tends to give faster look-up times, and 4.2.2.2 is an Anycast type DNS server run by Internet Carrier Level3 which has a reputation for quality peering, routing efficiency, and performance.